# Handling primary keys when syncing data

Tags: android, sql-server, wcf, synchronization

I am working on android application which will use a wcf service to interface it with the data store on the server. Data can be added and changed both from web site and the an my android client, and I need to reflect the newest state of the database. What is unclear to me is, what if I insert a row in the my local database (on the phone, which will be synced at the first possibility) and someone else inserts a row with the sane id ( primary key ) before I even have the possibility to sync my changes to the server.

I heard about row_version column in sql server, but I am not sure if I can and how I could use it in my case. Anyone has any idea on how to tackle this ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Two of the ways to handle this are:

- Have a primary key With 2 parts, the id of the database where the original insert was made and a sequence number.
- Use Guids as primary keys, the keys are generated in code and not by the database.

Since you are using SQL Server you should have a look at [MS Sync Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/Sync). But it may not be a Complete solution, since you are using Andriod.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your PK is and how you're syncing your mobile device to the server. Merge replication works with identity columns and I've seen it (that is merge replication) demoed on an android device.